# Find missing permutation

Tags: algorithm, heuristics

This problem was presented by google at a recent codejam round and it still haunts me how i didnt manage to solve it. please show me how it can be done:

> Go, go, Power Arrangers! Everyone loves this team of five superhero
>   high school students who wear the letters A, B, C, D, and E. When they
>   stand side by side to confront evil monsters, they arrange their team
>   in one of 120 possible different left-to-right orders, giving them
>   various different tactical superpowers. They are even more popular
>   than the Teenage Permutant Ninja Turtles!
>
> Some critics of the show claim that the team only has its arrangment
>   gimmick so that the owners of the show can sell 120 separate sets of 5
>   action figures, each of which features the team in a different
>   left-to-right order, glued to a base so that the set cannot be
>   rearranged. As an avid Power Arrangers fan, you have collected 119 of
>   these sets, but you do not remember which set you are missing. Your
>   119 sets are lined up horizontally along a shelf, such that there are
>   a total of 119 × 5 = 595 action figures in left-to-right order. You do
>   not remember how the sets are arranged, but you know that the
>   permutation of the sets is selected uniformly at random from all
>   possible permutations, and independently for each case.
>
> You do not want to waste any time figuring out which set you are
>   missing, so you plan to look at the letters on at most F figures on
>   the shelf. For instance, you might choose to look at the letter on the
>   eighth figure from the left, which would be the third figure from the
>   left in the second set from the left. When looking at a figure, you
>   only get the letter from that one figure; the letters are hard to see,
>   and the different team members look very similar otherwise!
>
> After checking at most F figures, you must figure out which of the
>   sets is missing, so you can complete your collection and be ready to
>   face any possible evil threat!
>
> Input and output
>
> This is an interactive problem. You should make sure you have read the
>   information in the Interactive Problems section of our FAQ.
>
> Initially, your program should read a single line containing two
>   integers T, the number of test cases, and F, the number of figures you
>   are allowed to inspect per test case. Then, you need to process T test
>   cases.
>
> Within each test case, the missing set of figures is chosen uniformly
>   at random from all possible sets, and the order of the remaining sets
>   is chosen uniformly at random from all possible orders as well. Every
>   choice is made independently of all other choices and of your inputs.
>
> In each test case, your program will process up to F + 1 exchanges
>   with our judge. You may make up to F exchanges of the following form:
>
> - Your program outputs one line containing a single integer between 1 and 595, inclusive, indicating which figure (in left-to-right order
>     along the shelf) you wish to look at. As a further example, 589 would
>     represent the fourth figure from the left in the second set from the
>     right.
> - The judge responds with one line containing a single uppercase letter A, B, C, D, or E, indicating the letter on that figure. If you
>     sent invalid data (e.g., a number out of range, or a malformed line),
>     the judge will instead respond with one line containing the single
>     uppercase letter N.
>
> Then, after you have made as many of the F exchanges above as you
>   want, you must make one more exchange of the following form:
>
> - Your program outputs one line containing a single string of five uppercase letters: the permutation corresponding to the missing set
>     (e.g., CADBE).
> - The judge responds with one line containing a single uppercase letter: Y if your answer was correct, and N if it was not (or you
>     provided a malformed line). If you receive Y, you should begin the
>     next test case, or stop sending input if there are no more test cases.
>
> After the judge sends N to your input stream (because of either
>   invalid data or an incorrect answer), it will not send any other
>   output. If your program continues to wait for the judge after
>   receiving N, your program will time out, resulting in a Time Limit
>   Exceeded error. Notice that it is your responsibility to have your
>   program exit in time to receive a Wrong Answer judgment instead of a
>   Time Limit Exceeded error. As usual, if the memory limit is exceeded,
>   or your program gets a runtime error, you will receive the appropriate
>   judgment. Limits
>
> 1 ≤ T ≤ 50. Time limit: 40 seconds per test set. Memory limit: 1GB.
>   The missing set, and the order of the remaining sets, are chosen
>   uniformly and independently at random. Test set 1 (Visible)
>
> F = 475. Test set 2 (Hidden)
>
> F = 150.

Comment: IMHO this problem is way to broad. At least trim down the problem statement to the _actual_ problem without all the narrative, pointers to in-accesible resources, and irrelevant input/output formatting. Also, what have you tried, and how did it not work? Was it too slow, or did ist just not get the right result, always or just in some cases?

Comment: Well my intention was to keep the problem in its original context. No i didnt expect an output. It's an algorithmics problem. Had i had an exact algorithm to implement i would've done it but i couldn't find a solution.

Comment: Have you seen the official analysis?

Comment: Granted, but 90% of that problem statement is irrelevant. You can leave it in as a reference, but you should post a re-worded, abbreviated problem description. Something like: Given an unknown list of 119 of 120 permutations of 5 items, you can ask F queries for a single item of that sequence of 595 items and then have to determine which permutation is missing". Is this about right?

Comment: I think I would try something like this: Test the first character of each permutation, i.e. query for 0, 5, 10, 15, etc. Now you know the first characeter of the missing permutation, i.e. after 119 queries you got it down from 120 to 24 possibilities. Not sure how to continue from there, but it might be a start.

Comment: The biggest unknown is what answer you want when you cannot reliably solve it, i.e. when F<148. Is it irrelevant, or do you want to maximize probability of correct answer?

Answer (score 4):

You could try something like this:

- use your first 119 queries to query the first element of each "block", i.e. the 0th, 5th, 10th, etc. element
- count how often you find each letter, and where; there should be 24 permutations for each starting letter, but for one there are only 23
- continue with those 23 permutations and query the second letter of those blocks, e.g. if the starting positions of those were 15, 40, 60, ..., query the 16th, 41th, 61th, ... letter
- again, count how often you find each second letter; there should be 6 for each, but for one letter there are only 5
- continue with those 5 and query the 3rd letter of those; for one of those, there will be only one permutation instead of two
- now you know the first three letters of the missing permutation; make a final query for the fourth (or fifth) letter of that single permutation with the same first three digits from the last step, and you can infer the last two digits of the missing permutation

This way, you will need 119 + 23 + 5 + 1 = 148 queries to find the missing permutation.

Example implementation in Python:

```py
import itertools, random, collections
permutations = list(itertools.permutations("ABCDE"))
random.shuffle(permutations)
permutations.pop()
flat_permutations = [c for p in permutations for c in p]

queries = 0
candidates = [i * 5 for i in range(119)]
missing = ""
for i in [0, 1, 2, 4]:
    where = collections.defaultdict(list)
    for t in candidates:
        queries += 1
        c = flat_permutations[t + i]
        where[c].append(t)
    c, candidates = min(where.items(), key=lambda item: len(item[1]))
    missing += c

# we queried for the 5th and used it as 4th in 'missing'
missing += next(c for c in "ABCDE" if c not in missing)

print("queries", queries)
print("missing", missing)
print("correct?", tuple(missing) not in permutations)
```

This will *always* find the missing permutation, but it will also *always*<sup>1)</sup> take 148 queries.

If F is smaller, you might just query random positions and then use probability to guess the permutation that least fits those guesses.

---

<sup>1)</sup> Technically, you *could* find it with fewer queries, e.g. if you are very lucky and after 100 queries you alredy have 4 letters with 24 positions each, you do not need to do the last 19 queries, but that would be pure luck, and the chances for this are rather slim.

Comment: Shouldn't it be 148? You have to query for present[4] according to the rules, right? Obviously you can find the last letter by process of elimination.

Comment: @HansOlsson Ah, you are right. Didn't remember that you only get that one char and not the entire permutation... fixed.

Comment: How would you update this implementation to check elements in succession (i.e. 1st, 2nd, 3rd, 4th instead of 1st, 2nd, 3rd, 5th)?

Comment: @EugeneYarmash Some time since I wrote this, but I guess you'd just change the loop to `for i in [0, 1, 2, 3]:`?